# insert date in oracle from java using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, date, prepared-statement

I am using *PreparedStatement* for inserting data in Oracle from Java.

Following is my query:

```
String query ="insert into table_name(ID, Date) values(?,(select to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(REPLACE('Wed May 29 09:26:59 IST 2013','IST','Asia/Calcutta'),'Dy Mon DD hh24:mi:ss TZR YYYY'),'Dy Mon DD hh24:mi:ss YYYY') from dual))";
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
pstmt.setString(1, ID);
pstmt.setString(2, "Fri Aug 02 12:38:35 IST 2013");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

But I am getting the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

So any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Update1**

I tried setting *Timestamp* :

```
pstmt.setTimestamp(1,Timestamp.valueOf("Fri Aug 02 12:38:35 IST 2013"));
```

But then I am getting exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
```

Comment: use a `java.sql.Timestamp` and `PreparedStatement.setTimestamp()`

Comment: Take a look at `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion parse your date string in Java and go with

```
String query ="insert into table_name(ID, Date) values(?,?)";
...
pstmt.setDate(2, date);
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that datatype of your field in databse is`Datetime` it will store your time stamp in database.

Comment: "Date" is different use "Datetime" to store timestamp

Comment: I am using Oracle10 and there is no datatype called Datetime, Date can store both date and time